# Play Framework - System.loadLibrary() only once per thread

Tags: java, c++, scala, opencv, playframework

I'm writing a webapp using Play Framework 2.1, that utilizes OpenCV (2.4.6) libraries. I didn't have any problems compiling OpenCV and getting the final .jar, but there is one remark that worries me in [the Java/Scala tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.6/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) for OpenCV:

> Note the call to `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`. This
>   command must be executed exactly once per Java process prior to using
>   any native OpenCV methods. If you don’t call it, you will get
>   UnsatisfiedLink errors. You will also get errors if you try to load
>   OpenCV when it has already been loaded.

I know Play Framework is multithreaded and the threads are reused between requests. Is there a way for me to call the `loadLibrary` function when each individual threads are spawned? Or am I misunderstanding how the thread pool works and I'm supposed to load the library once per request? What is the correct approach here?

[Edit:] I figured out I can put the `System.loadLibrary` code in the global configuration class, which will make all the threads share the library. The library isn't thread safe, so I think it's just an accident waiting to happen if I do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a problem - "This command must be executed exactly once per Java **process**" - it will suffice to call it once on app's start and you don't have to worry about different **threads**.

Bonus: It is possible to check if the library was already loaded (even if it's totally unnecessary), i.e.:

```
 def loadedLibs: Seq[String] = {
    val libs = classOf[ClassLoader].getDeclaredField("loadedLibraryNames")
    libs.setAccessible(true)
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    libs.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
      .asInstanceOf[java.util.Vector[String]]
      .asScala
  }

  def loadOpenCVOnDemand(): Unit = {
    val isLoaded = loadedLibs.map(str => str contains "opencv").reduce((x, y) => x || y)
    if(!isLoaded) {
      System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)
    }
  }
```

A whole another issue is if the native library's functions can be called concurrently. In OpenCV, it's not a problem at all:

> The current OpenCV implementation is fully re-enterable. That is, the
>   same function, the same constant method of a class instance, or the
>   same non-constant method of different class instances can be called
>   from different threads. Also, the same cv::Mat can be used in
>   different threads because the reference-counting operations use the
>   architecture-specific atomic instructions.

Comment: loading native libraries doesn't see to work at all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621262/fail-to-load-a-native-library-using-activator-play-framework